# call anonymous function javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to call a function passing argument.
Here is my code.

```js
var myfb;
var MyFaceBook = function(response) {
  this.response = response;
};

MyFaceBook.prototype.dd = function(_array) {
  console.log(_array);
}

MyFaceBook.prototype.doLike = function(_url) {  
  this.dd(_url);
  return false;
}

MyFaceBook.prototype.getTabList = function() {  
    return '<a href="#" onclick="'+this.doLike.call('http://facebook.com')+'"> Like </a> | <a href="#">Share</a> | <a href="#"> Comment </a>';
};

myfb = new MyFaceBook(response = array());
myfb.getTabList();
```

What I really need is when I click 'Like' button, I need to console the url i.e 'facebook.com' that I pass.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `call` (`this.doLike.call(...)`) to call a function, you can just do `this.doLike(...)`

```js
var myfb;
var MyFaceBook = function(response) {
  this.response = response;
};

MyFaceBook.prototype.dd = function(_array) {
  console.log(_array);
}

MyFaceBook.prototype.doLike = function(_url) {  
  this.dd(_url);
  return false;
}

MyFaceBook.prototype.getTabList = function() {  
    return '<a href="#" onclick="myfb.doLike(\'http://facebook.com\')"> Like </a> | <a href="#">Share</a> | <a href="#"> Comment </a>';
};

myfb = new MyFaceBook([]);
document.body.innerHTML += myfb.getTabList();
```

This is not the best way to do this. You should create links using [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), attach event listeners to them [`EventTarget#addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and then append those links to `DOM` using [`Node#appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```js
const MyFaceBook = function(response) {
  this.response = response;
};

MyFaceBook.prototype.dd = function(_array) {
  console.log(_array);
}

MyFaceBook.prototype.doLike = function(_url) {  
  this.dd(_url);
  return false;
}

MyFaceBook.prototype.getTabList = function() {  
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.innerHTML = 'Like';
    link.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.doLike('http://facebook.com');
    });
    document.body.appendChild(link);
};

const myfb = new MyFaceBook([]);
myfb.getTabList();
```

Comment: yes, that's does the work. But the function is executed automatically without click event. How can I prevent it from running automatically.

Comment: @user2542724 Is this what you expected?

Comment: Actually, when I click on "Like" link, I need to console the "http://facebook.com". But right now, the function doLike is called automatically when the script is loaded.

Comment: @user2542724 have you clicked `Like` link?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ponury-kostek 's answer, plus in the following line of code

```js
myfb = new MyFaceBook(response = array());
```

you could use

```js
myfb = new MyFaceBook("your response here");
```

in case of an array :

```js
myfb = new MyFaceBook(["your response here","another response..."]);
```

here is a full executable code that works :

```js
var myfb;
var MyFaceBook = function(response) {
  this.response = response;
};

MyFaceBook.prototype.dd = function(_array) {
  console.log(_array);
}

MyFaceBook.prototype.doLike = function(_url) {  
  this.dd(_url);
  return false;
}

MyFaceBook.prototype.getTabList = function() {  
    return '<a href="#" onclick="'+this.doLike('http://facebook.com')+'"> Like </a> | <a href="#">Share</a> | <a href="#"> Comment </a>';
};

myfb = new MyFaceBook(["my response"]);
myfb.getTabList();
```

Comment: yes, the above code works fine now. But the function 'doLike' is executed automatically without click event. How can I prevent it from running automatically.